# UIView layer renderInContext Memory not getting released

Tags: memory-management, crash, pdf-generation, automatic-ref-counting, calayer

We are trying to create multiple pdf files by using UIView.layer's renderInContext method

The below code run in a autoreleasepool.

```
---loop

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(documentDirectoryFilename, CGRectZero, nil);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    view =nil;

    pdfContext =nil
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

--loop ends
```

After couple of iterations resident memory increases to 20 mb and subsequent iteration adds to the total memory used.

Some how ARC is not releasing the memory used in rendering the pdf and thus the application crashes with low memory.

Application is using ARC

Any help or pointers to resolve the issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATED:
Thanks for the quick reply.

My apologies for having a typo in the pseudocode.
Here is sample code from a test project.

```
   -(BOOL)addUIViewToPDFFile:(UIView*)view newBounds:(CGRect)newBounds pdfFile:(NSString*)pdfFile{
BOOL retFlag =YES;

    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdfFile];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(documentDirectoryFilename, CGRectZero, nil);
   CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if([NSThread isMainThread]){
        NSLog(@"Main Thread");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Not in Main Thread");

    }
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    logMemUsage1();
    [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    pdfContext = nil;
    logMemUsage1();


return retFlag;

 }

  - (IBAction)createPdf:(id)sender {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

     @autoreleasepool {
    PDFViewController *vc = [[PDFViewController alloc] init];
    [vc loadView];
    NSString *PdfFileName =[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"TestPdf%d.pdf",i ];
    [self addUIViewToPDFFile:vc.view newBounds:self.view.frame pdfFile:PdfFileName];
    vc = nil;

  }
```

}
}

One more to point to add is that when application goes into the background on press of the hardware home button and comes back again to foreground the memory seems to get cleared and released.

I am expecting that after each iteration the memory which is used for creating the pdf should be released.

Comment: I reformatted the code such that it shows ... as code. Now you might see the problem? hint: You do one `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` per loop iteration, but have only one `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext` no matter how many times your loop has been executed ... Move it inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.My apologies for having a typo in the pseudo code.I have updated with sample code to create pdf from UIView